# How to disable the continual color annotation in heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

```
library(NMF) # other packages are welcome
car<-as.matrix(cars)
car[car<18]<-0
car[car>=18]<-1
aheatmap(car)
```

[image]

I would like to see only two colors in the legend: the 0 represents blue and 1 represents red.

Comment: The number of breaks in the legend can be changed [see documentation](http://nmf.r-forge.r-project.org/aheatmap.html): `aheatmap(car,color = "-RdYlBu2:1")`. However you will still have the graduation

Comment: Yes, it works better in your way, but the sill the graduation exits. Thanks all the same.

Comment: What about changing the red-blue style to yellow-red style?

Comment: [Please refer to the documentation](http://nmf.r-forge.r-project.org/aheatmap.html) __When the coluor palette is specified with a single value, and is negative or preceded a minus ('-'), the reversed palette is used. The number of breaks can also be specified after a colon (':'). For example, the default colour palette is specified as '-RdYlBu2:100'.__ so in your case, you can use the yellow-red palette from RColorBrewer: `aheatmap(car,color = "-YlOrRd:1")`